# Select Radiobutton when typing in Entry widget?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, tkinter

Is it possible to auto select a radiobutton as soon as you start typing in an entry widget box?
See this example:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("test 1")

v1 = IntVar()

options = [("Option 1",1), ("Option 2",2), ("Manual Option 3",3)]
Label(root, text="Which option?").pack(anchor=W)
for txt, val in options:
    Radiobutton(root, text=txt, padx=5, variable=v1, value=val).pack(anchor=W)

pcNameEntry = Entry(root, width=18)
pcNameEntry.pack(anchor=W)
```

It would look a lot more polished if the last radiobutton would be selected the moment you start typing in the entry box underneath...

It that possible?

Thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind an event to a keystroke in the Entry. The event should then set `v1` to 3.
Which, in code, looks like:

```
pcNameEntry.bind('<Key>', lambda e: v1.set(3))
```